# Implementation concerns regarding IndetityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, implementation

I have some questions regarding Identityserver4 in the following context:

I have a number of domains (domainA, domainB, domainC ect.) and I’d like all of them to use Identityserver4 for authentication, but I’d like only one implementation of Identityserver4 (with asp.net identity and EF) and have the all domains use this implementation as clients. All domains is in a hosted environment with MS SQL as database, if that has any relevance.

**Question 1:**

> Can IdentityServer4 run in a subfolder/area of domainA, and if so what are the necessary steps for getting this to work, e.g. the endpoints shown in the .well-known endpoint?

**Question2:**

> What are the pitfalls, if any, in hosting Identityserver4 in a subfolder/area under domainA, and also having domainA use Identityserver for authenticating users for the rest of the site, and how to avoid the pitfalls if there are any?

The authorization part that permits one user to do this and not that, and the opposite for another user is not the concern of Identityserver4, but the respective domains/sites own responsibility as I understand what I can find online. In order to make use of roles and roleclaims in asp.net identity core 2 in each domain/site there has to be a user in that domain/site, that has a reference to a user in Identityserver4 in order for the domain to use Identityserver4 for authentication.

**Question 3:**

> How do I avoid that the user must register both on the domain and in Identityserver4, one registration would be preferable and have the other made behind the scenes along with the reference?

I hope someone can provide the answers to one or all of my questions. Links to relevant blogs etc. are welcome, but I have scoured the web to find useful answers without any luck – hopefully some of you have better search engine skills than me.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

Yes you can. `IdentityServer` is `OWIN` hosted environment, thus it will be working as a `middleware` for your domainA, if you set it up so. Having a public endpoint entirely depends on your domainA.

---

**Q2**

The possible problem you will possibly encounter would be ***performance issues***. your domainA is going to receive requests from domainB and domainC including, of course, domainA itself. And `IdentityServer`'s checks-up such as authentications, validations, issuing tokens could be obviously time consuming jobs **compared to the plain HTTP requests**.

While the `middleware` is doing its job, the performance will hit slightly lower rate then domanB and domainC. But this is a necessary, unavoidable backfire because you added one another layer in your `HTTP` windows to deal with *the authentication / authorization / validation* issues on your service endpoints.

**You may want to scale out your** `IdentityServer` if the traffic gets much more huger then you expected and you feel your authorization server is dragging the whole services down. I recommend you to perform some stress tests beforehand and compare the performance differences between the services using the identity service and the services using none of that.

---

**Q3**

This could be highly opinionated answer. But as you mentioned `ASP.NET Identity` and `EF` I think you already know the answer. It seems that you're going to manage the token and identity information in your own hosted `DBMS`. Then consider it done with the possible duplicated registrations. Your `DBMS` and your implementation for storing and fetching such data will do it for you as long as you've done it right.

If you're not going to use `DBMS` for the identity and token data, and use a cache or a file system instead, then you will have to pour some efforts into the implementation in order to guarantee `concurrency` on the transactions for such data.